# Number of ways to seat people given certain constraints

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm struggling with this problem so if anyone can help, that would be appreciated. The problem goes like this:

Calculate the number of ways that k people can sit in a 2 x n matrix (n and k are obtained from the user through standard input). The matrix is also given by the user and can contain the following characters: '.' - people can sit here, '#' - people can't sit here.

People in the matrix can't be adjacent (that is if one person is situated at (row, column), another person can't sit at (row-1, column) or at (row, column-1) - notice that they can sit on (row-1, column-1)).

For example, if n = 3, k = 2 and given the following matrix:

```
..#
...
```

the answer would be 5. All possible ways to seat 2 people in the matrix are (u means that a person is sitting on that field):

```
u.#   .u#   ..#   u.#   .u#
.u.   u..   u.u   ..u   ..u
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: What did you try? Hint: wihout any `#`s, what would be the number of elements for `n` rows and `k` columns?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `k` - number of users, we have 2 rows and `n` columns

Comment: @Kozyr: that does not really matter. The point is that in order to come up with a solution, it might be worth first coming up with a mathematical formula that calculates it for a rectangular shape with all seats allowed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Seems it's quite challenging task to solve it mathematically even with all seats. I prefer paper and pencil to visualize the problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through `2 x N` matrix from left to right. On each column we could have only 3 states:

1. User on top position
2. User on bottom position
3. No users

So, on each step we could move from previous states and all we need to keep number of ways for each state and each number of users:

- State `Top` can move to states: `Bottom` or `None`
- State `Bottom` can move to states: `Top` or `None`
- State `None` can move to states: `Top`, `Bottom` or `None`

Answer is a sum of all states with `K` users.

**Sample code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum State: int
{
    Top,    // u
            // -

    Bottom, // -
            // u

    None,   // -
            // -
};

int main()
{
    int N, K; cin >> N >> K;
    string S[2]; cin >> S[0] >> S[1];

    map<State, map<int, int>> prev = { { None, {{0,1}} } };
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        map<State, map<int, int>> cur;

        if (S[0][i] == '.') {
            for (auto& w : prev[None])   cur[Top][w.first + 1] += w.second;
            for (auto& w : prev[Bottom]) cur[Top][w.first + 1] += w.second;
        }
        if (S[1][i] == '.') {
            for (auto& w : prev[None]) cur[Bottom][w.first + 1] += w.second;
            for (auto& w : prev[Top])  cur[Bottom][w.first + 1] += w.second;
        }
        for (auto& w : prev[None])   cur[None][w.first] += w.second;
        for (auto& w : prev[Top])    cur[None][w.first] += w.second;
        for (auto& w : prev[Bottom]) cur[None][w.first] += w.second;

        swap(cur, prev);
    }

    cout << (prev[Top][K] + prev[Bottom][K] + prev[None][K]) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```